# ¿Cómo puedo añadir un valor a una columna de un CSV con otro que saco de otro CSV con un loop for en Python3?

Tags: python, bucle-for, csv

Tengo un csv con artículos de *woocommerce* y un campo *wc_meta_secondary_image* para las imágenes secundarias de las variaciones del articulo.

Ese campo lo tengo que rellenar con la *meta_id* de la imagen que quiero para ese articulo, así que me he descargado la tabla *wp_posts* filtrando por tipo para descargar solo un CSV con imágenes y sus metas correspondientes. Así que tengo un CSV con imágenes y *meta_id* de las imágenes y otro con un listado de artículos con el campo correspondiente a la imagen secundaria vacío.

Quiero rellenar este campo vacío con la info del primer csv relacionando dos campos que existen en ambos csv que es la url del archivo de imagen en la base de datos.

Tengo este código:

```
with open("articulos_limpio_final.csv", "r") as datos_ok:  #abro el csv de los articulos
    datos_final = csv.DictReader(datos_ok)
    line_count = 0
    for row in datos_final:
        with open("id_s_images_final.csv", "r") as datos:  #abro el csv de las imagenes para ver cual es la fila donde esta mi url buscada
            datos_id = csv.DictReader(datos)
            line_count_2 = 0
            for row2 in datos_id:
#Aquí es donde busco los dos campos iguales en los dos CSV y si son iguales ya se que en esa row2 tengo la meta_id que estoy buscando para meterla en el campo del primer csv abierto
                if row2["Archivo"] == row["Imagen secundaria"]:
                    print(f'\t"La imagen del CSV {row["Imagen secundaria"]},y su id es {row2["meta_id"]}, has coincidence')# print de control para verificar que habia match entre los dos campos. Ahora quiero asignar row2["meta_id"] a row["Id_secundaria"] o crear un nuevo CSV con solo dos campos : SKU y ID_secundaria.
                    with open("articulos_con_id.csv", "w") as resultado:
                        fieldnames = ['SKU', 'id_secundary']
                        writer = csv.DictWriter(resultado, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                        writer.writeheader()
                        writer.writerow(row["SKU"], row2["meta_id"])
        line_count +=1            
        
print(line_count)
```

He probado varias opciones obviamente pero estoy atascado aquí:

```
writer.writerow(row["SKU"], row2["meta_id"])
```

Con este error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "e:\RESULTADO\Script ID fotos\id_fotos_secundarias.py", line 20, in <module>
>    writer.writerow(row["SKU"], row2["meta_id"])
> TypeError: DictWriter.writerow() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
> ```

Comment: El método `writerow(cadena)` recibe un sólo parámetro, tal como se explica en la documentación: `https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow`

Comment: Gracias. Si, eso vi en la documentación. Lo que no veo es la forma de iterar sobre las filas de un objeto dictReader e ir "guardando" ciertos campos de cada row en una lista o diccionario nuevos para luego escribir un nuevo CSV pasandole solo esa lista o diccionario como parametro a dictWriter o si habria una forma mejor de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Pues ya encontré la solucion:
Efectivamente, el metodo writerow recibe solo un parametro igual que dictWriter.
Asi que la solucion pasa por ir guardando los datos sobre los que iteramos en una lista secundaria que pasaremos al final como parametro a dictWriter.
La solucion la encontre en este enlace https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/update-column-value-of-csv-in-python/ donde hay 3 metodos para hacerlo.
Dos con dataframes de Pandas, que todavia no conozco y el tercero con el modulo csv, así que con ese ejemplo he modificado mi codigo que ha quedado así:
'''

```
import csv
  
op = open("articulos_limpio_final.csv", "r")
dt = csv.DictReader(op)
#print(dt)
up_art = []
for r in dt:
    #print(r)
    row = {'ID': r['ID'],
           'SKU': r['SKU'],
           'Nombre': r['Nombre'],
           'Imagenes': r['Imagenes'],
           'Imagen secundaria': r['Imagen secundaria'],
           'Id_secundaria': r['Id_secundaria']}
    up_art.append(row)
#print(up_art)
op.close()
op = open("id_s_images.csv", "r")
dt = csv.DictReader(op)
#print(dt)
up_images = []
for r in dt:
    #print(r)
    row = {'meta_id': r['meta_id'],
           'post_id': r['post_id'],
           'meta_value': r['meta_value'],
           'Archivo': r['Archivo']}
    up_images.append(row)
#print(up_images)
#print(up_art)
new_list = []
for art in up_art:
    for id in up_images:
        if id['Archivo'] == art['Imagen secundaria']:
            row = {'ID': art['ID'],
           'SKU': art['SKU'],
           'Nombre': art['Nombre'],
           'Imagenes': art['Imagenes'],
           'Imagen secundaria': art['Imagen secundaria'],
           'Id_secundaria': id['meta_id']}
            new_list.append(row)
            print ('has coincidence')
            #print (art)
            break
        #else:
            #print('no coincidence')
print(new_list)
op = open("AllDetails.csv", "w", newline='')
headers = ['ID', 'SKU', 'Nombre', 'Imagenes', 'Imagen secundaria', 'Id_secundaria']
data = csv.DictWriter(op, delimiter=',', fieldnames=headers)
data.writerow(dict((heads, heads) for heads in headers))
data.writerows(new_list)
  
op.close()
```

'''